# Algae terrarium: automatically empty bottles

Tags: oxygen-not-included

Algae terraria produce bottles of polluted water. Fine, but they pile up and the dupes don't pick them up automatically. Is there anything I can do about that?

FYI: There is a bottle emptier accepting polluted water and sweeping the bottles with 'K' does work, but I'd rather not have to keep doing that every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Did you build a bottle emptier that accepts dirty water?

Answer (score 4):

You did (almost) everything correctly already:
1. Place terrarium which produces pWater bottles.
2. Construct bottle emptier nearby.
3. Set bottle emptier to accept polluted water
4. do *not* set it to sweeping only (cause then it will accept only bottles marked with 'k')
5. raise the priority of the emptier sufficiently high

Important is step 5, where you set the priority of the emptier (also important might be the distance between bottle and emptier).
If your dupes have many tasks to do, you need to micromanage the priorities. 
You should also note that only one bottle can be emptied at the same time. So if you have 1000 bottles lying around, there will only be one transport task active at the same time (in that case you might want to add additional emptiers).

Later on you can also use an automated sweeper (conveyor tech) to empty the bottles for you.

Comment: Duplicants' priorities take priority over objects' priorities. You need to have a dupe with high supply priority lest they do other errands, and even priority 9 won't be enough.

Comment: Auto sweeper is the way to go here if you can get the Mechatronics skill

Comment: Auto-sweepers do not handle bottles without mods.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of options:

1) Place the bottle emptier very close to your terrariums, and set its priority a bit higher. Make sure to enable auto-bottling on the emptier, as well. If your dupes still aren't emptying the bottles, they have too much to do and you need to further tune your priorities. If space is at a premium around your terrariums, you might need to empty the bottles into a small reservoir with a pump to get rid of the water.

2) Leave the bottles alone and put down some Deodorizers. PH<sub>2</sub>O offgases PO<sub>2</sub>, which the deodorizers will clean. It doesn't take all that many cycles for the offgassing to provide more O<sub>2</sub> than the terrariums (I haven't played since shortly before release so this may have been tuned).

3) Use a mod [like this one](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/?id=1820866530) to add a piped output to your terrariums, so you can pipe the PH<sub>2</sub>0 directly to a sewer or sieve.

Comment: Auto-bottling has nothing to do with this case. It simply will make your dupes fill new bottles from wenches when there is any polluted water available in them.